# Sizing capacitor to avoid/supress current spike?

Tags: power-supply, current, capacitance

On a rather weak 5 V supply I need to power a circuit requiring around 650 mA in short spikes (20-50 ms). Outside of the spikes the circuit requires about 30 mA. The supply is able to supply sustained approximately 150 mA. Is there a formula - or guideline - for calculating the correct capacitor for such an application?

And, a follow-up question to the above question: Say, somehow, I figured out that 300 uF is "enough". Would there be any issue in selecting a "higher" value (for example 500 uF or 750 uF) instead?

Comment: You must specify the maximum tolerable Voltage ripple on the 5V rail caused by the current demand

Comment: What's your average current?

Comment: @tobalt - Not much. The other circuits in the 5v rail are quite sensitive. I don't have a specific number, but, not much.

Comment: @Andyaka - Average current of what? The entire system or the curcuit in question? Average of the circuit is approx. 45-55mA

Comment: OK, and like tobalt said in their comment, how much ripple voltage can you tolerate? Is the 150 mA a short circuit current of the 5 volt supply?

Comment: @MichaelLarsen unfortunately "not much" is really not a helpful figure. For example limiting voltage ripple to 1mV will require an at least 10x larger capacitor than for 10mV ripple. Wrt larger than "enough" capacitor. Yes this can be problematic, especially for weak power supplies which usually have a "max capacitive load" rating of a few 100 µF.

Comment: I'd expect the system to survive 100mV ripple - but the lower the better. The power supply is large enough - it's just not very responsive, so as the spike occours the voltage dips by more than 500mV which causes resets on associated MCU's. But, at the same time the power supply can drive a 1A servo no problem as it is quite "slow" to start up its power draw.

Comment: Where does 5 V come from? If some kind of DC/DC, if you have enough peak current capability to output 650 mA, you can consider placing the capacitor on the primary side. Otherwise, you will end up with a humongous large one. Assuming 100 mV allowed ripple, it's I=C x dv/dt, differentiate to It = C x deltaV. Solve for C: 650m*50m/100m = 32.5 F.

Comment: @winny the 5v comes from 24VAC via a LM2940CT-5.0. It's an older application and I'd prefer not to have to make changes to the PSU circuitry as we're redesigning the entire application in the next couple of years anyway...

Comment: I foresee that you only have a two options left because 30+ F is not feasible. Limit the peak current and/or duration of said circuitry or redesign from linear to a DC/DC to allow 650 mA peak current and place a tiny capacitor on the primary side of it, if the 24 Vac by itself can't handle it. Oh, and if you can source 150 mA, you can change 650 mA to 650-150 = 500 mA in the formula above. Your are still orders of magnitude away from feasible though..

Comment: Wait wait wait. I must have misplaced a decimal point there. 325 mF. Still unreasonably large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excess current (beyond PSU capability) need is 500 mA, for up to 50 ms. This equals \$Q_x=\$ 25 mC of charge needed in excess during the spike. For maximum ripple \$V_r=\$ 100 mV, you will need a capacitance of \$C=Q_x/V_r=\$ 250 mF. Also you need to replenish the charge in the times between the spikes and you have only 100 mA current available, so the spikes must not occur more often than about 250 ms.

This is a really large capacitance which will cause all sorts of issues during startup and shutdown. It will also consume a lot of cost and space. Part of the problem is, that the frequency of interest here (20 Hz'ish) is in the range that you don't normally cover with bulk caps, but with PSU feedback instead. It is probably much easier to change the PSU and make it more responsive. In that case, you might only need bulk capacitance to provide charge for maybe 1 ms.

Another option could be super capacitors, which come in several F sizes, but have a rather low voltage rating. The issue with startup and shutdown will remain however.

Comment: How did you arrive at \$Q_x = 25 mC\$?

Comment: It reads in two first sentences, 0.5A × 50 ms = 25 mC.